# connecting 2 databases through mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make a query with 2 databases on 1 server.

normaly I would do:

```
$qry ="
        SELECT
            A.id,
            B.id
        FROM
            databaseA.tableA
        INNER JOIN
            databaseB.tableB 
        ON
            A.id=B.id       
    ";
```

But now I work with Mysqli
So I cant just use.

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($qry)
```

I need a way to tell the statement to use both databases.
Can someone help me in the right direction?

Comment: *"But now I work with Mysqli So I cant just use"* - what were you using before?

Comment: This may help http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: Who said you can't use a conventional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should just be

```
$statement = $connection1->prepare($qry);
```

Only 1 connection is needed, as long as you have the proper rights to the databases

There was a problem with the ftp programme, causing the files to be disrupted.
That's the reason, it didn't work.